# C# Read ListBox-Content using Data-Templates

Tags: c#, listbox, datatemplate

I've got the following Listbox-Elementstructure...

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ContentBox" Margin="10,0,10,10.5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" SelectionChanged="ContentBox_SelectionChanged_1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="MyItem" DataType="{x:Type local:Benutzer}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Benutzername: " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="LBUsername" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=UserName}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Kennwort: " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="LBPassword" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Path=Kennwort}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Anmeldeversuche: " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="LBCount" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Path=LoginCounter}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Filling the List works fine with this code...

```
Benutzer _User = new Benutzer(p.UserName, p.Kennwort, p.Anmeldungen);
            ContentBox.Items.Add(_User);
```

The problem is, that I can't figure out, how to read the LBUsername, LBPassword and LBCount Contents when something is selected. Hope someone can help me - thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not using a Binding when you already used Bindings? Things will get alot easier when you follow the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from selection changed event. Use following code for getting selected data.

```
private void ContentBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ContentBox.SelectedItem != null)// ContentBox is your listbox
        {

           Benutzer obj = ContentBox.SelectedItem as Benutzer;
            if(obj != null)
            {
                string name = obj.UserName;
            }

            ContentBox.SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
```